# Missing Authentication with Azure Active directory option in Connected Services of Visual Studio 2019 .Net Project

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, visual-studio-2019

I have an existing .Net framework project and I am trying to implement authentication with Azure directory in it.
I am trying to add "Authentication with Azure Active directory" option from "Connected Services" of VS 2019 but it is missing.
I can see the same option in same project on another system.
[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried in multiple systems,Even I am unable to find the `Authentication with Azure Active directory` option in `Manage Connected Services`.

In `Visual Studio Installer` click on `Modify` =>select `Azure Development` => `Modify`.

[image]

I have taken references from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory) to  configure Authentication in .NET Framework Application.

- Create a new .NET Web Application and select the `Authentication` option.
  [image]
- Select the required `Authentication type` and `Domain` .
- Provide the `ClientID` from `AAD`.

[image]

- Click on create and continue to create new Application.
- In `Web.config` settings related to AAD will be added automatically.

```cs
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="******" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="******" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="***.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="******" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:*****/" />
  </appSettings>
```

- Now our application is configured with `Azure Active Directory Authentication`.
- When I run my application, it is redirected to the login page.
  [image]

Same issue is also discussed in [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/authentication-with-azure-active-directory-missing-1/1547831).

Comment: I want to add this Azure Authentication to existing.project as I am working on an old application on which several developers are working at a time.

Comment: Try to add the settings manually.